# C++ Not Calling Assignment Operator

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Ok, my code kind-of calls the assignment operator. I've tried this code in Code::Blocks and it works beautifully. However, in Rowley's Crossworks it fails to work. Both IDEs use the GCC compiler. Here is my dumb class:

```
template <typename T>
class Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator() { ptr = nullptr; }
        Iterator(const T* p) : ptr(p) {}
        virtual ~Iterator() {}

        // Other stuff

    protected:
        const T* ptr;
};
```

And here is my offending code:

```
void GetStuff()
{
    static Iterator<char> it;
    static char buf[4];

    // Place the data into buf

    it = buf;    /* NOTHING HAPPENS. Indeed no assembly is generated for this line. */

    Send(it, sizeof(buf));    // Where Send() accepts a pointer to an Iterator<char>
}
```

The assignment should set the Iterator class's pointer to `&buf[0]`, which I assume is what the default assignment operator should do using the `Iterator(const T* p)` overload (at least I THINK that's what should be going on.)

Why would no default assignment operator be called? Why would no code at all be generated?

EDIT: Clarity

Comment: I am no expert, but the compiler could be optimizing it away because you're not using `it`...

Comment: Try actually doing something with `it`

Comment: If that doesn't work, have you examined the preprocessor output?

Comment: Use a debug compilation - disable any optimization.

Comment: what exactly do you mean "nothing happens"?  what *should* happen?  What sequence of inputs corresponds to a set of observed outputs corresponding to "something happened"?

Comment: Where is your assignment operator defined?  You only show the copy constructor which is not used with "it = buf;".

Comment: How about describing the problem and providing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering in the hopes that someone, somewhere sees this and doesn't fall into the same trap. The problem was not with the C++ code it was with the way Crossworks works.

I have organized my code into `src` and `inc` folders in the directory. In Crossworks I have created "Dynamic Folders" which supposedly scan the directory and sub-directories and update the project view with changes. In addition, this rescan is not automatic. So this was my problem:

1. Create a new source file and header file and place them into their respective `src` and `inc` folders. Crossworks displays these files as if they were in the root directory.
2. Open the `.c` and `.h` files in Crossworks' editor.
3. Rescan the dynamic folder and `Remove` the `.c` and `.h` from the root. The `.c` and `.h` files created in step 1 should be displayed in the correct folder.
4. Make changes to the still open `.c` and `.h` file. Crossworks somehow was not making changes to the correct files as it still thought they were in the root **even though they were created in the subdirectory to begin with.**

This is my best guess as to what Crossworks was doing. I've been bitten by this issue before and spent several minutes puzzling over why my code was not compiling. The solution is to close the files, rescan the dynamic folder, and open the files again from the dynamic folder. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will likely optimize out or elide anything due to it not being used.  If you define your own assignment operator, the compiler can't make assumptions about its semantics.  Try putting in a `cout` or something and it will result in a print.

```
Iterator& operator=(Iterator rhs) {
    std::cout << "actually assigning\n";
    this->ptr = rhs.ptr;
    return *this;
}
```

But you needn't do this since the compiler will generate better code for you anyway that allows more optimizations (as you've already found)

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on some of the comments, compilers will aggressively remove statements that don't accomplish anything. Others have noted to compile in debug, but the dead code elimination will sometimes occur even with optimizations turned off. (Plus, sometimes it's the optimized assembly you want to see - I run into this when I'm trying to analyze little snippets.)

I'll sometimes use a little function like this, which has all the protections against being optimized out. Just call `func(it)`:

```
template<typename T>
__attribute__((noinline))
void func(volatile const T)
{
    asm ("");
}
```

This function reads: take any argument, do nothing with it, don't inline this function, and it has a body, so don't think you can safely skip it. But since the argument variable is now "used," it won't be optimized away.

Or can just anything in a different file, since you'd need link-time optimizations enabled in order for the compiler to cull it at that point.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have an assignment operator defined.  Try something like:

```
Iterator & operator = ( const T * p ) { ptr = p; return *this; }
```

Comment: The compiler would implicitly define an assignment operator for assigning another `Iterator`.
In this case it uses that one, and creates the temporary `Iterator` object using the copy constructor from a `const T*`. (because it is not marked as `explicit`, probably should be)

Comment: It is not needed. The assignment works via the implicit converting constructor.

Comment: How will a compiler make an implicit assignment operator for an encapsualted type?  The implicit assignment operator would be for Iterator< T > & operator = ( const Iterator< T > & );  Where is the implicit conversion of T * to Iterator< T >?

Comment: No idea what you mean by encapsulated type, but `buf` decays to `char*`. And there is `Iterator(const T* p) : ptr(p) {}`, where `T` is `char`.